# Can't interact with Ignite Gallery on Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, joomla-extensions

I have a problem with my new setup of Ignite Gallery on a Joomla 2.5 site. I am fairly new to setting things up in Joomla.

The issue is that I have my gallery thumbnails visible on the gallery page, but when I click on them they don't do anything. If they are setup to display and change a large image at the top of the gallery page, no image is displayed and it will not change to one when a thumbnail is clicked. If the thumbnails are setup to display a lightbox instead, then no lightbox pops up when the thumbnails are clicked.

I can only assume that I have missed some vital step, such as including a JavaScript declaration at the top of my template. I can't find any information saying that I need to add a script tag to my template though, nor can I figure out what should be on the template from the example galleries on the Ignite Galley website.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? I have not currently got a support account with the developers, but I will get one if no one Stack Overflow knows what is going on.

Thanks,
Terry Rozmus

Answer (score 0):

If you open your browser developer tools and look in the  tags for your site, there will most likely be 2 version of jQuery running, therefore will cause conflicts. If Ignite Gallery has an option to turn off jQuery, try doing this, else find out which file is including the jQuery file and replace it with the following:

```
<?php
  // load jQuery, if not loaded before
  if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
    JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
    $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "components/component_name/js/jquery.js");
  }
?>
```

Obviously change the path to whatever suits you

Comment: I tried removing all the other JavaScript from the template except for the reference to category_mt13.js which appears to be a core JS file for the Ignite Plugin. This did not change the way the Gallery is behaving, so it appears not to be a conflict with another script.

I did get a JavaScript error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: Options is not defined" in category_mt13.js. This appears to indicate there is at least one missing piece of JavaScript in my template, but I can't figure out from Ignite Gallery's examples waht it might be.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your website? Also, you might want to send the developers of Ignite Gallery an e-mail as it might be a bug. Sorry, can't really suggest a lot as it's a commercial extensions I don't have.